# JavaScript replace single quote with HTML code tag

Tags: javascript

I have the following string and am trying to replace it with an HTML code tag.

```
var stringdata = "Hello world, this is a `sample` string. Here is some CSS code for the string `.typetext{ color:#000; }`";
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello world, this is a <code>sample</code> string. Here is some CSS code for the string <code>.typetext{ color:#000; }</code>
```

I am using the following code, but it's just replacing the `with code tag and not wrapping the content inside the`

```
stringdata=stringdata.replace(/(`)/ig, "<code>$1</code>");
```

Comment: 'Cause you're only replacing ```/(`)/```, not ```/`([^`]+)`/```…

Answer (score 1):

You can replace '`' based on its count (if even it is a closing tag, if odd it is an opening tag)

```js
const stringdata = "Hello world, this is a `sample` string. Here is some CSS code for the string `.typetext{ color:#000; }`";

const {str: replaced} = stringdata.split("").reduce((lookup, c) => {
   let {count, str} = lookup
   if(c==='`'){
    count++
    str += count % 2 ? '<code>' : '</code>'
    return {count, str}
   }
   return {...lookup, str: str + c}
}, {
  count: 0,
  str: ""
})

console.log(replaced)
```